# What tooltip is Google using?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Does anyone by chance know what tooltip is Google Plus, Mail and others using ? I'm referring to the one with the black background.

And also, is it possible to have inside a tooltip some select items, for example I click on a button ( `<button type="submit"></button>` ) and by doing that a tooltip will fade in with some other buttons which can be selected or deselected. Is this possible or is there any tooltips that already have this implemented ?

Comment: There are hundreds of tooltip plugins, I expect Google make their own and not use jQuery, a screenshot would help.

Comment: For the simple tooltip go to gmail and hover the cog ( Settings ) button, you'll see the kind of tooltip I'm talking about. As for the second one, I only have it in mind, I looking for some examples right now.

Comment: Google definitely made that them selves.

Comment: @Jleagle Google DOES use jQuery at some places.

Comment: And there isn't a reproduction of Google's tooltip anywhere I assume ? Yes I know that git, I found it on Forrst.